# how to make a parking ground model

Tags: modeling

I am new to making the blender model, I want to build a blender model like the one show below, instead of making a whole parking image, would it possible to make a single parking spot with the cube, and make cube's texture material like the parking spot, at last creating many cube like parking spots sequentially to make it as a real parking spot?

[image]

Comment: Just create a tileable texture and use that on a plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Procedurally generated parking spots.

I've made this one just for fun. It probably would be easier just to make mask in some vector app like Inkscape or Illustrator then mix materials by it, but lets stick to pure Blender Cycles solution. This method is from an artist approach, there is a better solution for this shapes for sure but I don't know Node-fu as good to generate them by math.

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Setup:

[image]

### Breakdown:

**Stripes.**

[image: stripes]

**Mask.**

[image: mask]

### Final thoughts:

Even if it is looking complicated it is just stacking simple things like **Gradient texture** and **Wave texture** on top of each other and using this mix as a **Mask** for textures. I really don't know how to be more precise with it so any questions are welcome and I will extend this answer as needed.

Comment: This is really neat!

Comment: @seaturtle I'm lately amazed by Substance Designer and while I'm learning it a lot I'm also trying to bring this way of thinking about procedural textures to Blender. But without simple things like Shape, Blur/Sharp and Warp nodes it's sometimes pretty complicated to make such simple things like this one.

Comment: I've never heard of Substance Designer, it sounds interesting. And I wish that you could use compositing nodes in Cycles materials—that would add blur, for one thing.